# Not able to print table in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm trying to print table in HTML by using JavaScript. It just gives me a blank page when I try to print the table. Here's my HTML code:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="gen.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href = "index.css">
</head>
<body onload="print()">
    <div id="tt"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my JavaScript file:

```js
function print(){
    // console.log("?")
    var time = Number(localStorage.getItem("time"))
    // console.log(typeof time)
    var nClass = Number(localStorage.getItem("nClass"))
    var duration = localStorage.getItem("duration")
    var subjectsRaw = localStorage.getItem("arr")
    var subjects = JSON.parse(subjectsRaw)
     document.getElementById('tt').innerHTML = "<table border = 1>"
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    console.log('test')
    document.getElementById('tt').innerHTML = "<tr>"
    for (let j = 0; j < nClass; j++) {
        console.log('test2')
        document.getElementById('tt').innerHTML = '<td>' + subjects[Math.floor(Math.random() * subjects.length + 0)] + '</td>'
        
    }
    document.getElementById('tt').innerHTML = "</tr>"
    document.getElementById('tt').innerHTML = "<br>"
}
document.getElementById('tt').innerHTML = "</table>"
```

EDIT: Used DOM to print now.

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`, use DOM methods.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: I changed to DOM it's still showing blank page and no error in console. If I try to print something before table even that doesn't show.

Comment: `It just gives me blank page` can you check and verify no console erros has been happened?

Comment: Are you sure the data is in localStorage?

Comment: yeah I double checked both no console errors were reported and I can see data in local storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the element each time you assign to `innerHTML`, not appending to it. You can't construct HTML incrementally as you have with DOM methods, because every time you assign to `innerHTML` it parses it as a complete HTML fragment.

You should instead append to a string, and assign to `innerHTML` at the end.

```js
function print() {
  // console.log("?")
  var time = Number(localStorage.getItem("time"))
  // console.log(typeof time)
  var nClass = Number(localStorage.getItem("nClass"))
  var duration = localStorage.getItem("duration")
  var subjectsRaw = localStorage.getItem("arr")
  var subjects = JSON.parse(subjectsRaw)
  var html = "<table border = 1>"
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    console.log('test')
    html += "<tr>"
    for (let j = 0; j < nClass; j++) {
      console.log('test2')
      html += '<td>' + subjects[Math.floor(Math.random() * subjects.length + 0)] + '</td>'
    }
    html += "</tr>"
  }
  html += "</table>"
  document.getElementById("tt").innerHTML = html;
}
```